# set values to number pickers in a alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a alertdialog with a custom layout from a xml file. To get the number pickers working, I have to set some values to them. How can I manage this?

Global vars in ShowMap class:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert;  //dialog f. koord.
static Dialog d ;
NumberPicker np1, np2, np3, np4, np5, np6, np7, np8;
String abc[] = new String[] { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z" }; 
String zero_to_99[] = new String[100];
```

showDialog():

```
    public void showDialog()
{
    final Context context=getApplicationContext();
     //final Dialog d = new Dialog(ShowMap.this);

     //Creating the AlertDialog object
     final AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     //customDialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pick_coord,null);

     String txt_title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.txt_head_search_coord);
     d.setTitle(txt_title);

     np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p1);
     np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p2);
     np3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p3);
     np4 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p4);
     np5 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p5);
     np6 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p6);
     np7 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p7);
     np8 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p8);

     //d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_pick_coord);
     d.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             //Code to read out the pickers and work with the values
         }
     });

     d.setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

         }
     });


     d.setView(view);
     d.show();
}
```

setAlertDialogValues:

```
    public void setAlertDialogValues() {
    //Spalte
     np1.setMaxValue(60);   // max value 60
     np1.setMinValue(1);    // min value 1
     np1.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //Zeile
     np2.setMaxValue(25);   // max value Z
     np2.setMinValue(0);    // min value A
     np2.setDisplayedValues( abc );
     np2.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //100km Quadrat 1
     np3.setMaxValue(25);   // max value Z
     np3.setMinValue(0);    // min value A
     np3.setDisplayedValues( abc );
     np3.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //100km Quadrat 2
     np4.setMaxValue(25);   // max value Z
     np4.setMinValue(0);    // min value A
     np4.setDisplayedValues( abc );
     np4.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //Easting xx*
     np5.setMaxValue(99);   // max value 99
     np5.setMinValue(0);    // min value 0
     np5.setDisplayedValues( zero_to_99 );
     np5.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //Easting **x
     np6.setMaxValue(9);    // max value 9
     np6.setMinValue(0);    // min value 0
     np6.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //Northing xx*
     np7.setMaxValue(99);   // max value 99
     np7.setMinValue(0);    // min value 0
     np7.setDisplayedValues( zero_to_99 );
     np7.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

     //Northing **x
     np8.setMaxValue(9);    // max value 9
     np8.setMinValue(0);    // min value 0
     np8.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);


     np1.setValue(utmCoordElements[0]);
     np2.setValue(utmCoordElements[1]);
     np3.setValue(utmCoordElements[2]);
     np4.setValue(utmCoordElements[3]);
     np5.setValue(utmCoordElements[4]);
     np6.setValue(utmCoordElements[5]);
     np7.setValue(utmCoordElements[6]);
     np8.setValue(utmCoordElements[7]);
}
```

Where should I call this function? When I call it after `d.show` I'm getting an error...

Comment: or where should I findViewById(...)? Is there a method called when the alertdialog is displayed?

Comment: try posting the error.

Comment: I get a nullPointerException in line "np1.setMaxValue(60);  // max value 60"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.p1);
 ....
```

To:

```
 np1 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.p1);
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks, now there is no error but it has a display-error. The values are not displayed, please look to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22151739/3147701

Comment: This solves your previous problem. Please close this question.